# Alternative ways to call a function after another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the `.done` method to generate an order between related functions that must be executed one after the other. I usually have the ".done is not a function" error, due to the fact that its not very clear for me where can `.done` be placed.

In this case I have the same problem: I need first that `.newClassForm` animates till 0 height, and then `.infoText` to be filled with some text and be displayed, in this order.

If I use the `.done` method as it shows here, the mentiones error occurs.

**Where can `.done` be placed? How could I solve cases like this?:**

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.smartFormDiscard', function(){                     
    $('.newClassForm').animate({'height': 0}, 500);}).done(function(){
            $('.infoText').text("Crea una nueva clase").css('display','inline');
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is simply off. If you format your code properly, it would actually look like:

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.smartFormDiscard', function(){                     
    $('.newClassForm').animate({'height': 0}, 500);
}).done(function(){
    $('.infoText').text("Crea una nueva clase").css('display','inline');
})
```

i.e. `.done` is chained to the `.on` method.

I also believe you have to call `.promise` first on the jQuery object. So the actual code should be:

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.smartFormDiscard', function(){                     
    $('.newClassForm').animate({'height': 0}, 500).promise().done(function(){
            $('.infoText').text("Crea una nueva clase").css('display','inline');
    });
});
```

Since `;` usually terminate statements, you can already see at `);}).done`, that this cannot be right.

Comment: So .done is not meant to be placed after a functtion. I was wrong with that. Certainly the ; finished statement. Thank you, I'll tick in 8 minutes.

Comment: Made another change. I believe you have to call `.promise` first.

Answer (score 1):

use animate callback like this

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.smartFormDiscard', function(){                     
    $('.newClassForm').animate({'height': 0}, 500 , function(){
            $('.infoText').text("Crea una nueva clase").css('display','inline');
    });

});
```